# how to show function annotation in sublime text3

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3

[image: img]

How to show function annotation like the picture show.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of packages that help you do this. One of them includes [JavaScript Completions](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JavaScript%20Completions).

To install a package, look into [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) to learn how. You can generally do this by doing CMD+SHIFT+P and then choosing Install a Package.

Answer (score 0):

Try following step:

1. press CTRL+SHIFT+P, then see 
   [image]
2. type javascript or any other language that sublime text3 supports

   3.wait till then all pakaege install related the technology
3. and once it is done, then reopen the ID
   [image]